# matching multiple words to a text using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to match n-grams/(multiple words) from a list to a text/string.

My sample matching list contains words like:-

```
matching_list = ['Data Scientist',
 'Associate Research Scientist',
 'Post Doctoral Research Fellow',
 'Research Scientist',
 'Assistant Professor', 
 'c# developer', 
 '.net engineer']
```

My sample text after parsing contains words like:-

text = 'I am a Corporate Account Manager with experience as Data Scientist Associate Research Scientist Post Doctoral Research Fellow Research Scientist Assistant Professor .Net engineer c# developer'

I followed a procedure of converting matching list and text to small case letters and then search with the following code.

```py
import re

# Uncomment when Matching 4-gram words
#findnames = re.compile(r'([A-Z]\w*(?:\s[A-Z]\w*(?:\s[A-Z]\w*(?:\s[A-Z]\w*)?)?)?)')

# Uncomment when Matching tri-gram words
#findnames = re.compile(r'([A-Z]\w*(?:\s[A-Z]\w*(?:\s[A-Z]\w*)?)?)')

# Uncomment when Matching bi-gram words
findnames = re.compile(r'([A-Z]\w*(?:\s[A-Z]\w*)?)')
```

```py
def is_name_in_text(text, matching_list):
        for possible_name in set(findnames.findall(text)):
            if possible_name in matching_list:
                print(possible_name)
        return possible_name
```

```py
is_name_in_text(text, matching_list)
```

I am expecting for bi-gram match to get

```py
    Research Scientist
    Data Scientist
    Assistant Professor
    c# developer
    .net engineer
```

But, I get the following output

```py
     Data Scientist
     Assistant Professor
```

1) I am unable to match special characters.

2) Moreover, the matching is jumping 2 words for bi-grams, 3 words for tri-grams and so on. It is not moving the matching phrase word by word across the sentence, rather, I feel that bi-grams are jumping 2 words at a time, tri grams are jumping 3 words at a time if the matches are not found. This is causing problems if the bi-grams start at odd places and grams starts at even places and so on.

My list consists of 7 special character such as #, @, +, ., _, - and *

I need to fix special characters and word-by-word pattern match in the corpus. I am unable to come-up with a suitable re expression that does this like re.compile(r'([A-Z]\w*(?:\s[A-Z]\w*)?)').

I am not sure about the re expressions for tri-grams and 4-grams as well.

Comment: Check if this library helps https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to match word level n-grams, specifically word level bigrams.

However, the regex you provide: `([A-Z]\w*(?:\s[A-Z]\w*)?)` matches any string of word characters preceded by a character in the range `A` to `Z`, optionally followed by a single space and another such a string.

Using that regex would never match `c# developer`, since it doesn't start with `A` to `Z` and contains `#`. Nor would it match `.net engineer`, since that starts with `.`. Also, you're matching `.net engineer`, but it's in the text as `.Net engineer`.

Also, by using that regex and `findall`, the regex will consume the string in pairs of capitalised words, preventing reuse. So, after matching `Corporate Account`, it could never match `Account Manager`, since the `Account` part would have been consumed already. You're using a non-capturing group, but that still causes the regex to consume that part of the the string.

Assuming you do want to match case-insentive word level n-grams and you need to match special characters like `#`, I don't think you can achieve what you want with a single regex, but some fairly basic Python code gets you there.

Consider that filtering out any n-gram that has a part that's not made up entirely of word characters or your preferred special characters is probably not efficient. Why not simply split up the string over the spacing instead and find the n-grams you're looking for?

```
import re

text = 'I am a Corporate Account Manager with experience as Data Scientist' \
       ' Associate Research Scientist Post Doctoral Research Fellow Research' \
       ' Scientist Assistant Professor .Net engineer c# developer'

matching_list = [
    'Data Scientist',
    'Associate Research Scientist',
    'Post Doctoral Research Fellow',
    'Research Scientist',
    'Assistant Professor',
    'c# developer',
    '.net engineer'
]


def get_ngrams(words, n):
    return zip(*[words[m:len(words)-(1-m)] for m in range(n)])


def main():
    # simply split up the text, you could also just go words = text.split()
    regex = re.compile(r'[^\s]+')
    words = regex.findall(text.lower())
    # turn the list of words into ngrams of the needed length
    ngrams = list(get_ngrams(words, 2))
    # also create ngrams for the phrases in matching_list 
    # then link them to the phrases in a dict for easy reference
    matching_ngrams = {
        k: v for k, v in zip(
            [tuple(x.lower().split()) for x in matching_list], matching_list 
        )
    }

    # find all the matching ones and print the matching phrase when found
    for find_this in ngrams:
        if find_this in matching_ngrams:
            print(matching_ngrams[find_this])


main()
```

Note that this still generates duplicates, you indicated you expected each result only once. You can achieve that by flipping the loop and the comparison:

```
    for find_this in matching_ngrams:
        if find_this in ngrams:
            print(matching_ngrams[find_this])
```

This will go through the longer list more often, costing more time, but it will only print each phrase once if it is in the text. Alternatively, you could create a function returning all matches and putting them in a `set`.

To avoid the list, the inefficiency of the lookup and the needless `re`, I'd prefer this:

```
def get_ngrams(words, n):
    return zip(*[words[m:len(words) - (1 - m)] for m in range(n)])


def find_matching_ngrams(text, phrases, n):
    ngrams_phrases = {
        k: v for k, v in zip(
            [tuple(x.lower().split()) for x in phrases], phrases
        )
    }

    for ngram in get_ngrams(text.lower().split(), n):
        if ngram in ngrams_phrases :
            yield ngrams_phrases[ngram]


def main():
    text = 'I am a Corporate Account Manager with experience as Data Scientist' \
           ' Associate Research Scientist Post Doctoral Research Fellow Research' \
           ' Scientist Assistant Professor .Net engineer c# developer'

    matching_list = [
        'Data Scientist',
        'Associate Research Scientist',
        'Post Doctoral Research Fellow',
        'Research Scientist',
        'Assistant Professor',
        'c# developer',
        '.net engineer'
    ]

    print(set(find_matching_ngrams(text, matching_list, 2)))


main()
```

And possibly a bit more efficient:

```
def get_ngrams(words, n):
    for m in range(len(words)-(n-1)):
        yield tuple(words[m:m+n])
```

Comment: Hi Grismar, Thank you for your elegant solution. Your answer perfectly works for my problem. Now, I have another issue. Instead of printing, I wanted the function to return the matched words and then I keep appending the words to a list as I keep changing the text.

Comment: Hi @NewBie, note how the last complete solution actually yields the matched phrases from the text one at a time - you can straight up use that. To append to another list (or add to a set) for consecutive texts, I'd recommend just trying to code that yourself starting with the code above. If you run into specific issues, ask a new question, since explaining it here would be a bit off topic. Please accept the answer if you feel it answers your original question here.

Comment: Hi Grismar, All good. I made multiple changes to you code and I have got what I wanted. Thanks a lot.